# Why are the results different when I integrate an expression in different ways?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

When I integrate the expression like,

```
A1=(0.310314 ((0.00564116 - 4.25452 I) + (0.149772 - 55.6062 I) \[Beta] + \[Beta]^2 - (0. + 0.0765116 I) \[Omega] - I \[Beta] \[Omega]))/(236.578 + 3092.07 \[Beta] + 0.223032 \[Beta]^2 + \[Beta]^3 + 8.50904 \[Omega] + 111.212 \[Beta] \[Omega] +  0.0765116 \[Omega]^2 + \[Beta] \[Omega]^2) - (0.0239123 ((0.000620872 - 0.471257 I) + 0.0084749 \[Beta] - (0. + 0.0084749 I) \[Omega]))/((236.578 + 3092.07 \[Beta] + 0.223032 \[Beta]^2 + \[Beta]^3 + 8.50904 \[Omega] + 111.212 \[Beta] \[Omega] + 0.0765116 \[Omega]^2 + \[Beta] \[Omega]^2) (0.0732601 -I (55.7334 + \[Omega])))
```

Three ways

```
((Integrate[ A1 \[Rho][\[Omega]], \[Omega]] /. {\[Omega] -> \[Omega]1}) -
(Integrate[ A1 \[Rho][\[Omega]], \[Omega]] /. {\[Omega] -> \[Omega]2})) {\[Beta] -> 0.6295615718735122` + 0.07944775685111569` I}
```

```
((Integrate[A1 \[Rho][\[Omega]] /. {\[Beta] -> 0.6295615718735122` + 0.07944775685111569` I}, \[Omega]] /. {\[Omega] -> \[Omega]1}) - (Integrate[A1 \[Rho][\[Omega]] /. {\[Beta] -> 0.6295615718735122` + 0.07944775685111569` I}, \[Omega]] /. {\[Omega] -> \[Omega]2}))
```

```
Integrate[A1 \[Rho][\[Omega]] /. {\[Beta] ->0.6295615718735122` + 0.07944775685111569` I}, {\[Omega], \[Omega]2, \[Omega]1}]
```

give three different results

```
  0.356811 + 5.38461*10^-6 I
```

```
-0.407398 + 0.228095 I
```

```
0.355888 + 0.0000238939 I
```

where `\[Rho][\[Omega]]=0.758333 + 1/3 (-55.6062 - \[Omega])` and `\[Omega]1=-54.9468`,`\[Omega]2=-56.2655`.

What is the problem here? And how to determine which one is right?

Comment: Did you try `A1 = Rationalize[(0.310314 ((0.00564116 - 
           4.25452 I) + (0.149772 - 
            55.6062 I) \[Beta] + \[Beta]^2 - (0. + 
            0.0765116 I) \[Omega] - I \[Beta] \[Omega]))/(236.578 + 
       3092.07 \[Beta] + 0.223032 \[Beta]^2 + \[Beta]^3 + 
       8.50904 \[Omega] + 111.212 \[Beta] \[Omega] + 
       0.0765116 \[Omega]^2 + \[Beta] \[Omega]^2) - (0.0239123 \
((0.000620872 - 0.471257 I) + 
         0.0084749 \[Beta] - (0. + 
           ... + \[Beta] \[Omega]^2) (0.0732601 - 
         I (55.7334 + \[Omega]))), 0];` to avoid roundoff errors?

Comment: Pay your attention to `...` in the above (A part of the expression is omitted to be presented here.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The order of operations affects the precision. Use exact values until the final result and then use arbitrary precision rather than machine precision.

```
ρ[ω_] = 0.758333 + 1/3 (-55.6062 - ω) //
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;
ω1 = -54.9468 // Rationalize;
ω2 = -56.2655 // Rationalize;

βrule = {β -> Rationalize[
     0.6295615718735122` + 0.07944775685111569` I, 0]};

A1 = (0.310314 ((0.00564116 - 4.25452 I) +
          (0.149772 - 55.6062 I) β + β^2 -
          (0. + 0.0765116 I) ω - I β ω))/
      (236.578 + 3092.07 β + 0.223032 β^2 +
        β^3 + 8.50904 ω + 111.212 β ω +
        0.0765116 ω^2 + β ω^2) -
     (0.0239123 
        ((0.000620872 - 0.471257 I) + 0.0084749 β -
          (0. + 0.0084749 I) ω))/
      ((236.578 + 3092.07 β + 0.223032 β^2 +
          β^3 + 8.50904 ω + 111.212 β ω +
          0.0765116 ω^2 + β ω^2) 
        (0.0732601 - I (55.7334 + ω))) //
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;
```

Method 1

```
N[(
   (Integrate[A1 ρ[ω], ω] /. {ω -> ω1}) -
    (Integrate[A1 ρ[ω], ω] /. {ω -> ω2})) /.
  βrule, 15]

(* 0.342963552432318 + 0.002442574599151 I *)
```

Method 2

```
N[(
  (Integrate[
      A1 ρ[ω] /. βrule, ω] /. {ω -> ω1}) -
   (Integrate[
      A1 ρ[ω] /. βrule, ω] /. {ω -> ω2})),
 15]

(* 0.342963552432318 + 0.002442574599151 I *)
```

Method 3

```
N[Integrate[A1 ρ[ω] /. βrule, {ω, ω2, ω1}], 15]

(* 0.342963552432318 + 0.002442574599151 I *)
```

Comparing results,

```
% == %% == %%%

(* True *)
```

Comment: It is enough to rationalize  only `A1`  to obtain close results.

Comment: No, if you will remove Rationalize from ω1 and ω2 it will break N[, 15] it will not work for N[, 30]. This is a regression, see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172425/error-in-integral-representation-of-appells-series Same here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160695/real-integrand-complex-integral-result/160751?noredirect=1#comment651469_160751

Comment: Thank you all. And how can I set every number Rationalize globally?

Comment: You probably do not want to automatically rationalize all numbers. This would notably impact performance for all numeric calculations whether or not there were any precision issues. However, to **temporarily** do this, use `$Pre = (# /. {val_Real | val_Complex :> Function[{x}, Rationalize[x, 0]][val]} &);` then after the relevant calculations are done, use `$Pre=.` to reset normal behavior.

Comment: Thank you! @BobHanlon